# Regex everything else than the 4 digits

Tags: javascript

I would like to only retrieve the 4 digits in my strings. But im struggeling to find out to check if there is any 4 digit number.
I know i can match 0-9, but i dont know how to approach this.

examplestring:

```
"potato potato oniontat 4 k 4983 somethingelse potato";
```

result:

```
4983
```

How can i get the 4 digits that form a 4-digit number?

Comment: What’s the specific issue? What have you tried so far? Have you experimented with any of the sites that both teach, and allow you to test, regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex would be `/[0-9]{4}/`. Breaking it down:

- `/`: start of regular expression
- `[`: begin character group

  - `0-9`: match integers 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- `]`: end character group
- `{4}` Repeat last match 4 times
- `/`: end of regular expression

It can be executed with `Number(/[0-9]{4}/.exec('string 1234 string')[0])` (note the `[0]`)

Some example outputs:

- `hello 1234 world` => `1234`
- `foo 1 bar 2 baz 3456` => `3456`